# Unable to dockerize rails container, while using python

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, docker

Unable to dockerize rails container, while using a python call to perform a certain task. If I inherit from FROM ruby:2.7.1-alpine, what should I do in order to get the python runtime for my sidekiq container runtime

```
class FooWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(image_id, host)
    image_obj = Image.where(id: image_id).first
    file_path = rails_blob_path(image_obj.media, host: host)
    result  = `python app/lib/foo.py #{file_path}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install `python` environment in `Dockerfile` like next:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1-alpine
RUN apk add python3
RUN python3 --version
```

**Execution:**

```
$ docker build -t abc:1 .
$ docker run --rm abc:1 python3 --version
Python 3.8.10
```

If you want to use python2, just use `apk add python2` instead.